# Multivariable Calculus Application Question: Utility and MCRS

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, utility

> If a student has a utility function given by $$U(x_1, x_2) = −x_1 +
> > 10x_ 2^2 − 2x_1x_2$$ where $X_1 = 5$ and $X_2 = 20$. If this student was to
>   eat $5$ less hot meals per month, estimate the increase in the number of
>   pints of beer the student will need to consume if they are to maintain
>   their current utility.

I said that $$\frac{\partial U}{\partial X_1} = -1-2x_2 = -1 -2(20) =-41$$
$$\frac{\partial U}{\partial X_2} = 20x_2 -2x_1 = 20(20) - 2(5) = 390$$

When calculating that change in current utility, I start to run into trouble (I think).

$$ Δ = \frac{\partial U}{\partial X_1} Δx_1 + \frac{\partial U}{\partial X_2} Δx_2 $$
$$ 0 = (-41)(Δx_1) + (390)(5) $$
$$ \frac{1950}{-41} = Δx_1 $$
$$ Δx_1  = -47.56$$

So does that mean that the student needs to drink $47.56$ less beers to maintain the current utility? And is this possible when the student already only consumes $5$ beers to begin with?

Answer (score 1):

Is $X_1$=amount of pints of beer ?

Then the equation is $0=-41\cdot \Delta x+390\cdot (\color{blue}{-5})$. The change is negative.

The result for $\Delta x$ is smaller than -5 as well. You are right. It is not possible to compensate the 5 hot meals with beer.

Comment: Yeah, that's right. I actually just forgot to include the -5 in typing and calculated everything as if it was a minus five. So I still have a change in $X_1$ as -41.56 which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @RoySheehan You mean $\Delta X_1 =−47.56$  ? The algebric signs for summands with $X_1$   are always negative. So you have to drink less beer, if you eat less meals. Beer is not good, in this case. Here the student hasn´t drunk not so much beer, that he/she can compensate the 5 meals, which he/she is not eating anymore.

Comment: That's right. I found the change in $X_1 =-47.56$. Does this look correct to you, or do you think I could have gone wrong somewhere?

Comment: @RoySheehan It looks fine to me. :)